# Options menu get black with two screens (SIKULI)

Tags: linux, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot to a eclipse menu with sikuli, however I'm getting a black screenshot;

Example:

[image: Black rectangle]

This is what I get

[image: Screenshot of right click menu]

This is what I should be getting

Can you guys help me out ?!

Comment: Just in case its the thing -how did you take the working screenshot?

Comment: I used the Snipping Tool for the working screenshot and used sikuli to the other. @JourneymanGeek